# win32 api edit control can't be selected or edited

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I created an edit control using win32 api like this:

> CreateWindow("edit", "", WS_CHILD |
>   WS_VISIBLE, 0, m_position,
>   CONTROLS_WIDTH, EDITBOX_HEIGHT,
>   m_editorWindow,
>   (HMENU)GetNextComponentID(),
>   m_instance, NULL)

I can change the text from it using SetWindowText, but I can't select it or edit it's content - this is the purpose of an edit control, or not?:))

I read on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775458%28VS.85%29.aspx that I must use Edit_enable but I don't know where to find thin macro and I don't heave any idea how to enable editing. When I move the cursor over it the cursor changes to standard edit cursor.

Thank you for help!

Comment: It isn't obvious from your snippet nor is it typical behavior.  Post a small repro project to a file sharing service or paste bin if you want somebody to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `SetFocus(hwnd)` function.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try:

`HWND myWindow = CreateWindow("edit", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, m_position, CONTROLS_WIDTH, EDITBOX_HEIGHT, m_editorWindow, (HMENU)GetNextComponentID(), m_instance, NULL);`

`EnableWindow(myWindow, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
GetDlgItem(EditControlID)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
```

---

lol Oops.

Comment: It does not work. It is still not selected and can't be edited

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else that stumbles upon this question like me - having just run into this and debugged it, the issue is quite likely to be that you are missing the "TranslateMessage()" call in this loop:

```
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

The initial example I copied only called DispatchMessage in the loop, and until I added TranslateMessage I got the same behaviour as the original poster.